# Added value of using Secret Manager

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, passwords

I have a pretty standard application written in Java which also runs queries against a DB. The application resides on GCP and the DB on Atlas.

For understandable reasons, I don't want to keep the username and password for the DB in the code.

So option number 1 that I had in mind, is to pass the username and password as environment variables to the application container in GCP.

Option number 2 is using Secret Manager in GCP and store my username and password there, and pass the GCP Credentials as an environment variable to the application container in GCP.

My question is, what is the added value of option number 2 if it has any? It seems that option 2 is even worse from a security aspect since if some hacker gets the google credentials, it has access to all of the secrets stored in the Secret Manager.

I don't know what are the best practices and what is advised to do in such cases. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Having credentials in GCP secret manager will help you to keep track of all the secrets and changes in a centralized location and access globally from any of your app.

For a standard application where one JAVA is connecting to a DB, may not add much values.

You may look into kubernetes secret for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

If your application resides in GCP, you don't need a service account key file (which is your security concern, and you are right. I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c))

TL;DR use [ADC (Application Default Credential)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default) to automatically get the service account credential provided automatically on Google Cloud Component (look at [metadata server for more details](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)).

Then grant this component identity (by default or user defined, when supported), i.e. the service account email, to access to your secrets.

And that's all! You haven't secrets in your code and your environment variable, neither the login/password, nor the service account key file.

*If you have difficulties to use ADC in Java, don't hesitate to share your code. I will be able to help your to achieve this.*

Answer (score 0):

To use Secret Manager on Google Cloud you need to install the Secret Manager Java SDK Libraries. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) shows how to get started with the Cloud Client Libraries for the Secret Manager API, you only need to go to the Java section.
This Libraries helps you to access your keys in order that it can be used by your app.

The following [link](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/managing-secrets#secretmanager-get-secret-java) shows how to get details about a secret by viewing its metadata. Keep in mind that viewing a secret's metadata requires the Secret Viewer role (`roles/secretmanager.viewer`) on the secret, project, folder, or organization.

I recommend you to create a special Service Account to handle the proper permissions for your app, because if you don’t have a SA defined, the default SA is what is going to generate the request, and it is not secure. you can learn more about how to create a service account in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating)

On the other hand, you can find an example on how you can  use the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-java) that contains a good example  of finding your credentials automatically, that's more convenient and secure than manually passing credentials.